# Google vision API load credentials from file

Tags: java, credentials, google-cloud-vision

I want to use a different credentials file when creating my Annotator client. I am currently able to do it with the transalte API like so:

```
 Credentials creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream("path/to/credentials.json"));
 return TranslateOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(creds).build().getService();
```

Is there an equivalent way of doing it with the `ImageAnnotatorClient`?

Edit: I am working with google cloud java sdk version: 1.16.0

Answer (score 9):

`Credentials`  -> `CredentialsProvider`

`ImageAnnotatorSettings.Builder` -> `ImageAnnotatorSettings` -> `ImageAnnotatorClient`

Example (mostly copied from the docs):

```
Credentials myCredentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(
    new FileInputStream("path/to/credentials.json"));

ImageAnnotatorSettings imageAnnotatorSettings =
    ImageAnnotatorSettings.newBuilder()
    .setCredentialsProvider(FixedCredentialsProvider.create(myCredentials))
    .build();

ImageAnnotatorClient imageAnnotatorClient =
    ImageAnnotatorClient.create(imageAnnotatorSettings);
```

- ImageAnnotatorClient: `com.google.cloud.vision.v1.ImageAnnotatorClient`
- ImageAnnotatorSettings: `com.google.cloud.vision.v1.ImageAnnotatorSettings`
- ClientSettings.Builder: `com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientSettings.Builder`
- FixedCredentialsProvider: `com.google.api.gax.core.FixedCredentialsProvider`
- ServiceAccountCredentials: `com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials`

Note: The above is for Java. The [API for C#](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Vision.V1) is different.

Comment: What version is this? I am linking against 1.16.0 and most of the methods you state in your example are not there

Comment: Just noticed the docs you referenced are for version 0.8.3 and it seems they have removed many of the methods and classes since.

Answer (score -1):

```
private static ImageAnnotatorSettings  setImageAnnotator() {
    Credentials myCredentials = null;
    try {
        myCredentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(
                new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Pictures\\Cloudvision\\credentials.json"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        ImageAnnotatorSettings imageAnnotatorSettings = null;
        try {
            imageAnnotatorSettings = ImageAnnotatorSettings.newBuilder()
            .setCredentialsProvider(FixedCredentialsProvider.create(myCredentials))
            .build();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Add some explanation perhaps?